# Why i am getting datatype mismatch error?

Tags: php, postgresql

> SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: argument of WHERE must be
>   type boolean, not type integer LINE 1

```
    $sql = "SELECT mod_modulegroupcode, mod_modulegroupname FROM module "
            . " WHERE 1 GROUP BY `mod_modulegroupcode` "
            . " ORDER BY `mod_modulegrouporder` ASC, `mod_moduleorder` ASC  ";


    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $commonModules = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $sql = "SELECT mod_modulegroupcode, mod_modulegroupname, mod_modulepagename,  mod_modulecode, mod_modulename FROM module "
            . " WHERE 1 "
            . " ORDER BY `mod_modulegrouporder` ASC, `mod_moduleorder` ASC  ";

    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $allModules = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $sql = "SELECT rr_modulecode, rr_create,  rr_edit, rr_delete, rr_view FROM role_rights "
            . " WHERE  rr_rolecode = :rc "
            . " ORDER BY `rr_modulecode` ASC  ";

    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":rc", $_SESSION["rolecode"]);


    $stmt->execute();
    $userRights = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: You should try to determine which one of your queries is throwing error. I guess it's second one with `WHERE 1`, but you should prepare https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well, the message sais it all. Where expects boolean. You are giving it integer. Where 1. Thats useless btw. Why put where, with always true condition?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a datatype mismatch error because the `where` clause of a SQL statement expects you to provide conditions, not integer values. Your third query has a condition for its `where` clause, but your first two try to just give an integer value. There are some programming languages where `1` treated like "true", but SQL is not one of those languages.

Given that you're assembling the SQL with your code, if there's no condition to provide for the `where` clause, then just leave the `where` clause out, like this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT mod_modulegroupcode, mod_modulegroupname FROM module "
            . " GROUP BY `mod_modulegroupcode` "
            . " ORDER BY `mod_modulegrouporder` ASC, `mod_moduleorder` ASC  ";
```

But then you're going to have a problem because `mod_modulegroupname` is not aggregated. Since you're not doing any aggregation, I suggest just taking the `GROUP BY` clause out, too. You should also take the backticks out of your `order by`. This would leave you with:

```
    $sql = "SELECT mod_modulegroupcode, mod_modulegroupname FROM module "
            . " ORDER BY mod_modulegrouporder ASC, mod_moduleorder ASC  ";
```

If I can kindly say so, it sounds like you should do a SQL tutorial.

Comment: If i remove the where clause then it will show the another error SELECT mod_modulegroupcode, mod_modulegroupname FROM module GROUP BY mod_modulegroupcode ORDER BY mod_modulegrouporder ASC, mod_moduleorder ASC SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "module.mod_modulegroupname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT mod_modulegroupcode, mod_modulegroupname FROM module ... ^

Comment: An aggregate functions include `count()`, `sum()` and so on. Since you aren't calling any of them, you don't need a `group by` clause -- which is what I was talking about in the second part of my answer.